# Nuget, IoC and scanning

Tags: visual-studio, inversion-of-control, nuget, .net

On my current project we are using Nuget to bring in dependencies on things like NHibernate, we use Ninject as our IoC container (although that's not an important detail of the problem I'm trying to solve) and we use Ninject's scanning functionality for establishing our bindings.

This all works fine but the problem that I'm facing is that I've gone through the trouble of making my Data Access Layer be exposed to the Application Layer in a Presistence Ignorant fashion but Ninject needs to have access to the NHibernate Dlls at scan time. If I wasn't using Nuget to pull in dependencies then this could easily be solved with a post build step to copy the dependencies from wherever I had decided to put them in my source tree.

However, with using Nuget my understanding is that the path to Dlls could change in the package directory as dependencies are upgraded. I definitely don't want to solve this problem by using Nuget in my Coposite Root projects (services, UX, etc...) and so I'm trying to figure out a clean way to get the dlls that I need at scanning time available in my Composite Root projects execution directories.